# Error when using a facts counter library Countup.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i wanted to make fact counter for a theme i am developing. I decided to go with Countup.js. I loaded in my Index.html and everthyinh properly and tried to execute a basic function but it shows that CountUp is not defined in developer console in chrome. Here is the error.
Uncaught ReferenceError: countUp is not defined
    at custom.js:9
(anonymous) @ custom.js:9

My js code---

```
 var numAmin = new CountUp("counter1", 0, 500);
 numAmin.start();
```

My HTML code  ---

```
 <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-5x fa-inverse targetone" id="counter1"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to place jquery before countup.js and run script after document loads.

and add class="countupthis" and attribute numx="" to all elements you want to count up.

Set numx attribute to the number you want to count to.

```css
.facthold {text-align:center; display:inline-block; border:1px solid black; padding:10px;}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="facthold"><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
  <span class="countupthis" numx="28">2</span><div>Desktop users</div>
  </div>
<div class="facthold"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-2" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
  <span class="countupthis" numx="70">23</span><div>Mobile users</div>
  </div>


  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countup.js/1.8.2/countUp.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var options = {  
        useEasing: true,
          useGrouping: true,
          separator: ',',
          decimal: '.',
          prefix: '',
          suffix: ''
      };
      $('.countupthis').each(function() {
        var num = $(this).attr('numx'); //end count
        var nuen = $(this).text();
        if (nuen === "") {
          nuen = 0;
        }
        var counts = new CountUp(this, nuen, num, 0, 1.5, options);
        counts.start();
      });


    });
  </script>
</body>
```